# How do I get Rails to use this particular MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've been making Rails sites with sqlite3 on my local host, but I also have mysql installed in two places, both with MAMP and on its own on my hard drive.  Using sqlite3 is easy because you have to do nothing, but, due to a gem that I wish to use http://www.enkiblog.com/ (which says it requires mysql or postgres) I have to leave the easy world of sqlite3 for now.  So I have to do some configuration to specify which mysql on my system my next Rails app will use, and how would I do that? I don't want to use the MAMP mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use the macports mysql? That's exclusively what I use with my rails apps in development.

Comment: @Preacher thanks, didn't realize that macports had it. So can you answer the question and explain how I would use macports mysql? I'm a bit of a noob....

Answer (score 2):

#### Your app

Update your `database.yml` to something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: yourdb_development
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Notice the `socket` parameter? You can set up your two MySQL servers to use different sockets and here you specify which one you want to use.

Add configuration for `test` and `production` environments in a similar manner.

#### MySQL part

You can specify location of socket file in a MySQL's config file (usually named `my.cnf`), like this:

```
 [mysqld]
 socket=/path/to/socket

 [client]
 socket=/path/to/socket
```

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-mysql-sock.html) for more information. Where to find config files on your machine - that's out of scope of this question. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, but it's not a complete answer:) Can you explain how to set up my MySQL servers to use different sockets?

Comment: Thanks very much Sergo, I can't accept it as the right answer until I get it to work and know that it works, so I have to figure out all the other stuff that wasn't part of the scope of the question :)  The mysql documentation is not very clear. I don't know what's the difference between [mysqld] [client] etc.

Comment: `[mysqld]` is for server settings, `[client]` for client command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

The enki gem supports sqlite3, they even use it in their default config example. They just mention only mysql and postgres in the readme.

IMO a gem not supporting sqlite3 would be a huge red flag.

https://github.com/xaviershay/enki/blob/master/config/database.example.yml